# Ideal Siebel EIM component level Log setting

Tags: siebel

What is the ideal eventlevel log settings for the siebel component "Enterprise Integration Mgr".

The problem is while running the EIM job, I provide the highest value for sqlflag, traceflags and error flags, still I am not getting the detailed log for the PICKLIST_VALUE error, to find the column.

Kindly advise.

Thanks, 
Kriti

Answer (score 0):

This issue is faced when there is a LOV value (Bounded Picklist) which is not getting resolved. To resolve this first you need to identify the columns which are populating the LOV i.e picklist or dropdown, then verify that the value being pushed in that column is present in the List Of Values..

If still the error is not resolved then please provide the ifb file details

Answer (score 0):

You can set the below log levels to debug the issue that you are facing.

```
SQLFlags = 8
ErrorFlags = 1
TraceFlags = 3
```

Apart from this, you can check the column associated to the Picklist based field. Check the below property in Siebel Tools under for a Column.

```
LOV Type
LOV Bounded
Translate
```

If LOV Bounded is TRUE, then, during import, EIM checks the values against the values contained in a list defined in the LOV Type property.

If LOV Type and Translate property is populated, then Siebel stores the LIC value in that particular column for a specific LOV value.

Hope in this way you can track and debug the issue.